# Salesforce and Angular with separate servers

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, cors

I have two sets of servers:

1. apache serving up html/js/css pages in the angular flavor
2. SalesForce backend rest apis serving up Json

Salesforce has OAuth authentication, but it is not letting the javscript even perform an OPTIONS call in order to figure out if it can do the POST call it really wants to:

[image]

Is there any way to get around this without a proxy or jsonp?

is the Salesforce APEX Rest API configured wrong? the source domain is already whitelisted...

**Update:**
so some angular code to make the call:

```
var config = { 
    method: 'POST',
    url: SalesforceRestApi,
    headers: {
        Authorization: "OAuth "+authToken,
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf"               
    },
    data : caseRequest,     
};

var http = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$http');

http(config).then(function(response){ console.log(response); });
```

this code here returns the good old Chrome error:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/xxx/v1/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://sample.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.*

Comment: What code are you using to make the call? You might just be making the call incorrectly. Or forgetting to use your security token in your password. Or any number of other things.

Comment: i've updated the question to show some sample code.. the rest of the app is calling 3 other backend services to get resources, authentication, etc and those calls are all working fine...

Comment: As far as I understand what you want to do, there’s no way to get around this without a proxy, given that the CORS restriction which causes that error message is enforced by your browser. If that Salesforce server won’t even respond to an OPTIONS request, it seems very unlikely it would otherwise be configured to allow what you need even if you could get past that.